# scaffold multiple apiController asp.net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I would like to make a ApiController of every Class/Model in a specific directory.

I'm using asp.net core 2.0 in VS 2017

Any suggestions? So I don't have to add them manually?

Comment: Hire an AI intelligent enough to do that.

Comment: By which you mean: Impossible and stupid questions?

Comment: Impossible but not necessarily a stupid one. This can be a genuine requirement to not to do them by yourself as the number of models may be too large. In that case also someone has to do that manually for you.